# Combining multiple strings in Cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray, stringwithformat

I want to be able to combine each index so that I get @"Biology Teacher A BK 1", but so far I have been unsuccessful. This is what I have so far, but I do not know where to go from here.

```
@interface ListTableViewController () <UISearchDisplayDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *className;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *teacherName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *blockNumber;

@end

@implementation ListTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.className = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"Biology",
                  @"English III",
                  @"Chemistry",
                  @"Algebra II",
                  @"Morality", nil];

self.teacherName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    @"Teacher A",
                    @"Teacher B",
                    @"Teacher C",
                    @"Teacher D",
                    @"Teacher E", nil];

self.blockNumber = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    @"BK 1",
                    @"BK 3",
                    @"BK 6",
                    @"BK 2",
                    @"BK 1", nil];
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to concatenate the strings. Please show that code.

Comment: go with key and value using dictionary you will got solution..

Comment: @user1118321 you can use the code, I wrote in answer...

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 1):

It Will work:

```
   for (int i = 0 ; i< self.className.count; i++)
    {
      NSString *temStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",[self.className objectAtIndex:i] ,[self.teacherName objectAtIndex:i],[self.blockNumber objectAtIndex:i] ];
      NSLog("%@", tempStr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i< self.className.count; i++)
{
  NSString *temStr = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [self.className objectAtIndex:i]] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [self.className objectAtIndex:i]]]
  NSLog("%@", [temStr stringByAppendingString:[self.blockNumber objectAtIndex:i]])
}
```

Comment: How could space added here in between as he wanted?`(@"Biology Teacher A BK 1")`

Comment: Doesn't this create multiple NSString objects in memory? It would seem better to just use a single [NSString stringByAppendingString] invocation and use three string formatters and provide the objectsAtIndex within the parameters. Depending on how many iterations are made, you can be making a lot of unnecessary extra NSString objects, even if they are only held in memory for the duration of the current loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
int total = self.className.count;
NSMutableArray *combinedName = [NSMutableArray array];
if (total == self.teacherName.count && total == self.blockNumber.count)
{
   for(int i=0;i< total;i++)
    {
        NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [self.className objectAtIndex:i],[self.teacherName objectAtIndex:i],[self. blockNumber objectAtIndex:i]];
        [combinedName addObject:str];
   }
}
else 
   NSLog(@"Cann't combine");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This teaches me how to get the information out of the loop also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 //Assuming three array are in same length

 NSMutableArray *combineArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for(int i=0; i<[[self className] count]; i++)
 {
      [combineArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [[self className] objectAtIndex:i],[[self teacherName] objectAtIndex:i], [[self blockNumber] objectAtIndex:i]];
 } 

 NSLog(@"%@", combineArray); //here is your output.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
NSMutableArray *combinedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < [self.className count]; i++)
{
    NSString *combinedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",[self.className objectAtIndex:i],[self.teacherName objectAtIndex:i],[self. blockNumber objectAtIndex:i]];
    [combinedArray addObject:combinedString];
}
NSLog(@"Combined array is :\n %@",combinedArray);
```

Comment: is this a copy of tapas pal's answer

Comment: @Joshua It is a coincidence that both the answers are similar.
But it does not mean its a copy.
By the way this question is not so complex to answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, fairly ugly though.

```
self.className = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Biology",@"English III",@"Chemistry",@"Algebra II",@"Morality", nil];
self.teacherName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Teacher A",@"Teacher B",@"Teacher C",@"Teacher D",@"Teacher E", nil];
self.blockNumber = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"BK 1",@"BK 3",@"BK 6",@"BK 2",@"BK 1", nil];

NSMutableArray *combinedNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if (([self.className count] == [self.teacherName count]) && [self.className count] == [self.blockNumber count]) {
    for (int index = 0; index < [self.className count]; index++) {
        [combinedNames addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [self.className objectAtIndex:index], [self.teacherName objectAtIndex:index], [self.blockNumber objectAtIndex:index]]];
    }
}

for (NSString *string in combinedNames) {
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

and that outputs:

```
Biology Teacher A BK 1
English III Teacher B BK 3
Chemistry Teacher C BK 6
Algebra II Teacher D BK 2
Morality Teacher E BK 1
```

**Update**

Looks like this was posted already by others before I could finish getting it put together. I don't see that they verify that the array's are all of the same length though. You can use anyones answer; it might be wise to verify that all of the array's contain the same number of objects prior to trying to iterate through them.